# Validation issue preventing database update using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using the following PHP code to update information in a database but before the update can occur, I am prompted to complete all fiels even though all of the fields hav already been completed

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Here's my code

```
<?php

$update = strip_tags($_POST['update']); 

$username = strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['username']));

$olspassword = strip_tags($_POST['oldpassword']);

$newpassword = strip_tags($_POST['newpassword']);

$firstname = strip_tags($_POST['first']);

$lastname = strip_tags($_POST['last']);

$gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);

$address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);

$zipcode = strip_tags($_POST['zip']);

$contact = strip_tags($_POST['con']);

$email = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);

error_reporting(0);



if($update)
{




if($username&&$oldpassword&&$newpassword&&$firstname&&$lastname&&$address&&$zipcode&&$contact&&$email)
{

 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db(brightlights) or die(mysql_error());

 $updatecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM tb_user WHERE username='$username'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($updatecheck);
 if($count<=1)
 {

 if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword))
 {

 mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET
     username = '$username',
     password = '$newpassword',
     Firstname = '$firstname',
     Lastname = '$lastname',
     gender = '$gender',
     address = '$address',
     zipcode = '$zipcode',
     contact = '$contact',
     email = '$email'
     WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['password'] = $newpassword;
     $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $firstname;
     $_SESSION['Lastname'] = $lastname;
     $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
     $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
     $_SESSION['zipcode'] = $zipcode;
     $_SESSION['contact'] = $contact;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     session_write_close();
     echo "Succesfully Updated!";

    }else
     echo "Password not match!";
   }else
    echo "Username already Taken!";
  }else
   echo "Please fill up all form!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Very bad correct the formatting first

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason:

```
$olspassword = strip_tags($_POST['oldpassword']);
/// code
if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword)) {
```

The codeblock

```
if($_SESSION['password']==($oldpassword))
```

will always be false because $oldpassword is never set. You have a typo here:

```
$olspassword = strip_tags($_POST['oldpassword']);
```

See the variable $olspassword?

Comment: oh sorry for my ignorance didnt see that , now i have already change that now it always say password didnt match ,

Answer (score 0):

```
if($username&&$oldpassword&&$newpassword&&$firstname&&$lastname&&$address&&$zipcode&&$contact&`&$email)
```

make it like

```
if(isset($username) && isset($oldpassword)  and so on
```